# Should retag-only edits push a question to the top of the list?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When a question (or answer) is edited, it goes to the top of the list on the front page, as 'active' - but should that still happen if the only change is a re-tag?

I ask this, as every time anyone has a retagging session (as I have just done), you end up swamping the front page with a load of old questions, and I don't think that really helps.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

It's designed that way and a [similar suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers/119488#119488) was declined by Jeff.

I agree with [Nicol Bolas's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119488/132547)

> It would be good if this request were re-evaluated, in light of modern
>   edit reviewing technology.
>
> Paŭlo Ebermann speaks correctly about this issue when it pertains to
>   slower sites. A site that only gets 50 questions per day is still a
>   good site. But if you make 20 edits, you're pushing good questions off
>   the top.

Maybe it's time to change your name, not that changing mine to [MoveMoreCommentsToTop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24490/132547) did any good.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO retagging, if done properly, renders a question more focused and easier to find. Also, questions tagged with one's favourite tags are highlighted in the list. With this in mind, it does make sense for tag edits to bump the questions to the top of the list since that's a way of saying to potential answerers "hey here's a question you might have missed".